# UCMA as a shared service

Tags: c#, skype-for-business, ucma

Does anyone knows if it is possible to make your **UCMA** application as a shared service across multiple domains?

What I am thinking is, that the application will have a collaboration platform for connecting to N `Skype` for Business servers, which of cause has to be within same **MPLS** for reachability. But I am not sure if this is even possible??

Anyone has some experience in this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called as federation and can be done just by exchange configuration. See below links:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297982(v=exchg.141).aspx